# fetchall() loading indicator (simple and easy) in react-redux web app with axios

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, spinner

i have simple react-redux app with asp.netcore back-end.i want to use loading indicator like spinner like that etc or icon to show before the data is loaded.
my component is Courses.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import CourseList from "./CourseList" ;
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";

  const Courses =(props)=> {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let course = useSelector(state => state.course.list);
    const courseList = course.sort((a, b) =>a.updatedOn.localeCompare(b.updatedOn));

      useEffect(() => {
         dispatch(actions.fetchAll())
           
      
        }, [])
   
          return(
           <div>
          {courseList.loading && <em>Loading ...</em>}

        <CourseList
             courseList={courseList}          
          
       
               /> </div> 
                );  
               
    }
   
   
    export default Courses;
```

here is action for fetchall
courseActions.js

```
import courseApi from "../_services/courseApi";
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';


const formateData = data => ({
    ...data,
   // age: parseInt(data.age ? data.age : 0)
})

export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
      courseApi.course().fetchAll()
      
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        }
        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
}
```

here is courseReducer

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {
    list: []
    
}


 export const course=(state = initialState, action)=>{

    switch (action.type) {
     
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            
            return {
                
                 ...state,
                list: [...action.payload]
            }
               // remaining switch cases for simplicity
        }

 }
```

i have tried many options but could not find any simple and useful solution . i tried to set loading and setLoading in component but in these lines courseList becomes undefined.
`let course = useSelector(state => state.course.list); const courseList = course.sort((a, b) =>a.updatedOn.localeCompare(b.updatedOn));` 
i have used material-ui in app so icon with material-ui or simple loading... or simple image will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ternary operator in your return statement.

```
return(
    <div>
        {loading === true ? (<h1>Loading...</h1>) : (<CourseList courseList={courseList}/>)}
    </div> 
);
```

The other thing you need to make sure of is to update setLoading(false) after the fetch call in your effect otherwise the "Loading..." will never go away. I'm free typing this in let me know if it doesn't work & I will write up the code in an editor.

You can sub in a material-ui progress component if you want instead of the Loading... text I put in the example look here: https://material-ui.com/components/progress/